# Is there any relation between the Bar name 'Quindecim' and the Bartender 'Decim'?

Tags: death-parade

Was the Bar named because of Decim or something? They are spelled same and pronounced in the same way! Is there a relation mentioned?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The former owner of Quindecim was 'Quin'

[image]

She was then replaced by 'Decim'

[image]

Hence, it's definitely not a coincidence that the name of the bar is Quindecim.

As the [Wikia article on Quindecim](http://death-parade.wikia.com/wiki/Quindecim) states:

> **It is likely the arbiters Quin and Decim were named so for working on the fifteenth floor.**

There is no evidence of this. One thing is for sure though, Quindecim wasn't named after the arbiters since Quindecim means 15 in Latin and that's the name of the floor the bar is on.

Hence, it's very likely that Quin and Decim were both named after the bar. However, nothing was ever stated in the anime or the movie 'Death Billiards', so we can never truly know.

Comment: *"since Quindecim means 15 in Japanese"* are you sure, i though 15 in japanese was [juugo (十五)](http://japanese.about.com/od/japanesevocabulary/a/numbers.htm)

Comment: @Memor-X My bad. Corrected it.

Comment: Oh so it was the other way around(-_-')... The bartenders were named by bar..

Comment: @abhishah901 Lol yeah.

Comment: Quin- usually means 5 as in quintent, deci- often means ten as in decimal. So it's not that far fetched